# How to run a method on the first call to a .NET dll?

Tags: c#, dll

**My scenario**
Many classes in my DLL leverage some common services like logging. These common services need to be initialized. Since I don't know which classes will be constructed first, I include code similar to this in all constructors

```
Logger.Configure();
```

**Question**
Is there a way to subscribe to an event when my DLL is first loaded so that common services are initialized there, therefore allowing my classes to assume that the common services are ready for use.

I looked at the [AssemblyLoadEventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but the example demonstrates its use in a context of an executable, where the event is registered in the Main method when the application starts up.

Comment: It _looks_ like you might be using log4net?  Could you add a small wrapper to it so that instead of calling `GetLogger` on a log4net object, you instead call it on your wrapper?  That way, the first time it's called, it can call `.Configure()`, then call the original `GetLogger`

Comment: Yes, I am using log4net and I am already doing what you suggested - Logger in my example is a wrapper and it ensures that log4net is configured only once. But this is not the problem I am trying to solve. My question is how do remove this call (Logger.Configure()) from all my classes that rely on log4net while ensuring that log4net is configured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy thing to do would be to use the [*class constructor*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) (aka *static constructor*) in the classes that require it, so it would be executed *once per class*. But that still feels *not right*.

But you could encapsulate the calls (as per James' suggestion), and then do your initialization in the class constructor of your encapsulation class, so you write the code once and you run the initialization once.

... or the more complicated thing to do would be to define a *module initializer*. This is a piece of code that runs when your assembly is loaded, just what you're looking for. But it's not that easy to access, since the C# compiler doesn't provide a way to write one out of the box.

This is where [Fody/ModuleInit](https://github.com/Fody/ModuleInit) comes into play. It's a *weaver*. You write a class, then, after compilation, Fody turns your class into a module initializer. Whether it's worth the hassle for your particular case (over the encapsulation technique) is up to you to decide.

Comment: There is one more option, if you are using ASP.NET 4 or newer you can use [PreApplicationStartAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute.aspx) to have a method that is called when the DLL is loaded by IIS.

Comment: I am not using ASP.NET. 
I was suspecting that I would have to resort to something like PostSharp, thank you for confirming that that is the route to go.

Comment: @AlexT actually I wanted to encourage you to provide an implementation of `ILog` yourself (say `internal class LogForwarder : ILog`), delegating all calls to a *real* logger, and use the static constructor of `LogForwarder` to do the initialization. Then always use `LogForwarder` in your code instead of the `ILog` provided by log4net. Using Fody would certainly work, but I don't think it's necessary for this particular task.

Comment: Even though I agree with your suggestion of implementing ILog, doing so does not address the initial question - how to avoid calling (directly on indirectly) Configure method in all my constructors. At the same time, Fody (or similar) does provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Starting C# 9 you can try [ModuleInitializer attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/general?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003978#moduleinitializer-attribute)

There are some limitations, for example [ca2255](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2255)